# How to run a launch.json configuration when VSCode starts

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to run a configuration from launch.json when VSCode starts.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Possibly helpful / related: [Start app when opening project in VS Code?](/q/51049955)

Comment: @user Indeed it's very helpful. I'll go down the `tasks` path if I cannot find a way to do it with launch configuration.

Comment: you can add a feature request to the [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) extension

Answer (score 0):

open vs Code >>> then >>> type your simple cpp program such >>> "Hello world >>> then >>> open run at the status bar at the top of VS Code >>> then >>> chose  add configuration >>> then >>> your launch.json would be ready but it needs some configurations >>>> the following code has most of the configurations you need >>>
*** modify this path "miDebuggerPath": "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe" with the gdb path in your computer .... good luck bro

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    //"version": "0.2.0",
    //"configurations": []
        // Use IntelliSense to learn 
    // about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions 
    // of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: 
    // https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug with g++",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
              //There I have got error Property keys must be doublequotedjsonc
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't any attributes which allow the configuration to launch when VSCode starts.